# Extract date from string using regular expression - SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, parsing, extract

Say I have a field numCommande with a string "1610131223ZVV40" where 161013 is a date in form yymmdd.

Is there any way in SQL to extract that 13/10/2016 date from the string field ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it always the first six characters? No need for regular expressions if so, `substr()` and `to_date()` would be enough. What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes is always the first 6 caracters, thanks

Comment: Why is it 31/10/2016 not 13/10/2016?

Comment: it was an error .. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Column_Name,1,6), 'YYMMDD'),'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM TableName
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce715/5

Answer (score 3):

If the 'date' is always the first six characters, you can extract those with a plain `substr()` call:

```
substr(numCommande, 1, 6)
```

which gives you `'161013'`; and then convert that string to a date with a suitable format model:

```
select to_date(substr(numCommande, 1, 6), 'RRMMDD') from your_table;
```

Quick demo with static value instead:

```
select to_date(substr('1610131223ZVV40', 1, 6), 'RRMMDD') from dual;

TO_DATE(SU
----------
2016-10-13
```

Comment: Upvoting for use of `RR` over `YY`